# Why rust compiler needs type annotation here?

Tags: rust

I'm making some experiments on Rust's GAT and try to constraint multiple gats into one generic called `Eff`.

The code finally compiles, but I noticed that in the main function the compiler need type annotation for the `join` function but I think this is not necessary since I have already added constraint that `M: Join<F<T> = <M as Effect>::F<T>>`, any explanations?

```rust
trait Effect {
    type F<T>;
}

trait Functor {
    type F<T>;
    fn fmap<A, B>(fa: Self::F<A>, f: impl FnMut(A) -> B) -> Self::F<B>;
}

struct Eff;

impl Functor for Eff {
    type F<T> = Vec<T>;

    fn fmap<A, B>(fa: Self::F<A>, f: impl FnMut(A) -> B) -> Self::F<B> {
        fa.into_iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}

trait Point {
    type F<T>;
    fn point<A>(a: A) -> Self::F<A>;
}

impl Point for Eff {
    type F<T> = Vec<T>;

    fn point<A>(a: A) -> Self::F<A> {
        vec![a]
    }
}

trait Join {
    type F<T>;
    fn join<T>(xs: Self::F<T>, ys: Self::F<T>) -> Self::F<T>;
}

impl Join for Eff {
    type F<T> = Vec<T>;

    fn join<T>(xs: Self::F<T>, ys: Self::F<T>) -> Self::F<T> {
        let mut xs = xs;
        xs.extend(ys);
        xs
    }
}

impl Effect for Eff {
    type F<T> = Vec<T>;
}

fn logic<M: Effect, T>(a: <M as Effect>::F<T>, i: T) -> <M as Functor>::F<<T>::Output>
where
    M: Functor<F<T> = <M as Effect>::F<T>>,
    M: Point<F<T> = <M as Effect>::F<T>>,
    M: Join<F<T> = <M as Effect>::F<T>>,
    T: ops::Mul<T, Output = T> + Copy,
{
    let b = M::fmap(a, |a: T| a * a);
    let c = M::fmap(M::point(i), |a: T| a * a);
    //M::join(b, c) // this dont compile, the compiler said it need type annotation
    M::join::<T>(b, c)
}

fn main() {
    let zs = logic::<Eff, i32>(vec![1, 2, 3], 7);
    println!("{:?}", zs);
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, rather than having `let mut xs = xs;` in your `join` function, you could directly declare `xs` to be mutable in the function signature, with `fn join<T>(mut xs: Self::F<T>, ys: Self::F<T>) -> Self::F<T> { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you've named them the same `T` in `type F<T>` and `fn join<T>` are completely independent generic parameters. So when you call join it's type can not be inferred from the associated type `F<T>` so you have to specify it.

Comment: Can compiler infer T from join’s parameters?

Comment: No, they are generic in both cases `<M as Functor>::F` and `<M as Join>::F`

Comment: But with rust analyzer, ra has already inferred both the type of b and c contains T

Answer (score 0):

You can never what a type is from determining what its associated type is, since multiple types can have the same associated type.

The `i32` can be inferred, though, by replacing it with `_`.